# Manipulation an array of pluck in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

From a controller action that effects a search

```
where('created_at >= ?', Date.today).pluck(:article_id, :weight)
```

I wish to attempt in the view the equivalent of a ruby contain method on the first item in this array and present the second item of the array if it exists

```
  <% if @sfridos[0] == article.id %>
    <%= @sfridos[1] %>
  <% else %>
```

but maybe I'm mixing ruby and rails metaphors...